# Alterar a cor do cabeçalho do tema "Material" do pacote "rmdformats" para uma saida html no Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Gostaria de alterar a cor do cabeçalho do tema "Material" do pacote "rmdformats" para uma saida html do rmarkdown.

Quero alterar de verde para azul apenas o cabeçalho, mantendo toda as demais estruturas e cores

Estou com dificuldades de encontrar a solução

````
---
title: "Sample document"
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
    self_contained: false
    thumbnails: true
    gallery: true
    fig_width: 11
    fig_height: 6
    df_print: kable
runtime: shiny


---



```{r, echo=FALSE}

library(DT)


datatable(
  iris, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print','colvis')
  )
)


```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode incluir um chunk de CSS no corpo do arquivo .Rmd, para definir os atributos visuais dos elementos HTML da página que é gerada.

Nesse caso específico, é preciso incluir, nesse chunk CSS, um seletor que identifique o cabeçalho, para então definir a cor de fundo desejada por meio da propriedade `background-color`. Um seletor possível seria `div.header-panel`.

Assim, incluir o chunk abaixo deve alcançar o resultado desejado:

```css
div.header-panel {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda